# Converting a string for DateTime usage using sprintf formatting

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way how to take a string and be able to use it in a DateTime. This is an example (obviously giving an error because of incorrect parameters):

```
$string = sprintf('strtotime("second monday of october", mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 1, %d))', 2014);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $string);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

The reason why I want to achieve this is to be able to have the year be determined by other factors depending where it is located in my class: meaning that `$string` will be created on the fly and will be used later to output a date. My question, is there an alternative to this or is it just not possible and the year **must** be pre-determined. Any hand would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to know the second Monday of October for a variable year?

Comment: @TomFenech well in some ways yes. I'm creating a holidays class that allows users to add their own holidays but don't want to add a year necessarily until the holidays need to processed...not sure if I'm being clear enough.

Comment: OK, so you want to store the rest of the date but leave the year until later? It sounds like you should store the partial data you have separately and only generate the DateTime object when you have all of the information available.

Comment: @TomFenech I guess that's the only way. The `$string` variable in my example outputs a literal string `strtotime("second monday of october", mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 1,2014))`. It would have been great if there was a way to parse it into a timestamp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to get second october of a dynamic year, try doing:

```
$my_year = 2014;
$string = strtotime(sprintf('second monday of october %d', $my_year));
```

and use the `$string` to get formatted date